# Images in view controller changing height for unknown reason

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

My images in interface builder keep going back to a larger height than I want them to, after I change the height to make it the same as the width, which makes them appear to be not as close to the bottom of the view as they should be with my "bottom space to bottom layout" constraint of 15. Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

[image: Screenshot]

I have no constraints to do with height. Only equal widths. But I change the height to make it the same as the width and it straight away goes taller again. How do I stop the images going taller?

Comment: Why don't you make a constraint for height?

Comment: @WMios I need the images to become a little larger on larger devices. I could consider constraining the height and then changing the constrained heights to be a little bigger in the bigger size classes. Thanks for the idea. I would still like to know why these images are growing taller.

Comment: +1 for using height as constraint THEN altering it per Size class. You might also add an aspect ratio contraint on images. Then prioritize: fitting all 3 of them horizontally is more important THEN the height...